# Сигнал при запуске, повторном запуске программы

Tags: qt, c++

Добрый день-вечер. У меня есть функция, которая принимает аргументы, такие как url и title, типа QUrl и QString соответственно. Как соединить сигнал и вызвать функцию, если программу (!) запустили-перезапустили? Моё предположение было таково:

```
connect(&app, SIGNAL(appStarting(QUrl,QString)), this, SLOT(getTitle(QUrl,QString)));
```

Оправдается ли оно?

Comment: А зачем сигнал/слот? Почему бы в main'е не вызвать нужный метод?

Comment: Лишние потери памяти при вызове программы без параметров

Comment: Вы что-то не то думаете, или я. Наверное я. Что значит "Лишние потери памяти при вызове программы без параметров"? Можете подробней описать задачу?

Comment: Нет, все же это я не так подумал, когда писал. Просто надо было парсить параметры и при нулевых висеть в памяти, но не отображать. При наличии параметров возвращать интерфейс и уже визуализировать действия. Извините, развёл детсад :]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В конструкторе главного окна делайте соединение и будет вам счастье